# Rabbitmq web manager failed to login in as a administrator and error in console

Tags: html, google-chrome, rabbitmq

I`ve created a new user and set that as an **administrator** but still failed to log in after times of trial. However, I find some information in **console**, but can not solve it after enable-disable plugins and multiple times of re-installation of rabbitmq-server.
BTW I am using CentOS 7.9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the question by changing browser from chrome to IE, edge also works.